# Saving first key/value pair in Postgres HSTORE via Rails Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hash, hstore

I am working on my Ruby on Rails application and this application has a Model called 'User'. This model has a database column (in my Postgres database) called 'remark'. And this 'remark' field is of the type HSTORE. It stores a hash with extra information about this user.

I am using a method which saves the value of a parameter (params[:info]) into this 'remark' field with a key 'info'. This code works.

```
def save_info_for_user(info)
    @user.remark = { :info => info }
    @user.save
  end
```

And this code doesn't work **when** the database field **is empty** . So only when it holds a minimum of one key/value pair it is possible to save a new value like this.

```
  def save_info_for_user(info)
    @user.remark['info'] = info 
    @user.save
  end
```

It gives the following error:

```
   > undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

And this code works neither:

```
  def save_info_for_user(info)
    @user.remark[:info] = info 
    @user.save
  end
```

It gives the same error

```
> undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

And after some testing I found that *'remark[:info]'* holds a different value than *'remark['info']'*

Very confusing to me.

**My question:** 
Why does

```
@user.remark[:info] = info
```

gives that error. It should know that the database field 'remark' is a hash because its type is defined as HSTORE?

Hope someone can explain whats going on here and how to make this method futureproof.

Answer (score 1):

> It should know that the database field 'remark' is a hash

Its **type** is a hash, all right, but its current **value** is `NULL` (these two are completely separate things). Meaning that it's unknown. Not even an empty hash (because that would be a known value).

So to futureproof this you make sure that `remark` is, at minimum, an empty hash before attempting any updates on it.

```
  def save_info_for_user(info)
    @user.remark ||= {}
    @user.remark['info'] = info 
    @user.save
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio! Sounds logical now

Answer (score -2):

Please try this. hopefully it will work for you.

```
def save_info_for_user(info)
  @user.remark = { "info" => info }
  @user.save
end
```